# Elastic Search size to unlimited

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Am new to elastic search. Am facing a problem to write a search query returning all matched records in my collection. Following is my query to search record

```
{
   "size":"total no of record" // Here i need to get total no of records in collection
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "first_name": "vineeth"
      }
   }
}
```

By running this query i am only getting maximum 10 records, am sure there is more than 10 matching records in my collection. I searched a lot and finally got size parameter in query. But in my case i dont know the total count of records. I think giving an unlimited number to size variable is not a good practice, so how to manage this situation please help me to solve this issue, Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not very common to display all results, but rather use `from`and `size` to specify a range of results to fetch. So your query (for fetching the first 10 results) should look something like this:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "first_name": "vineeth"
        }
    }
}
```

This should work better than setting `size` to a ridiculously large value. To check how many documents matched your query you can get the `hits.total` (total number of hits) from the response.

Comment: Thanks for the help, in my case i don't know how many matched records in my collection. So i cannot set it to any static value. 
when i take hits.total as u said, i have to run the same search query twice i think. First run a search query to find hits.total. Then assign total size in the second query. Is it that way ?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your problem is. Assuming there are 21 results for your query. You call ` { from: 0, size: 10 }, ...` and get the first 10 results and the number of total hits (21). So when you need the results 11-20 you make another request `{from: 10, size: 10 } ...`. Now you want to get the final (21.) item, you cast call again `{from: 20, size: 10 }` you will now get 1 hit in your response `hits.hits`. When you want to know how many results a query will return, you can use a [count](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html)

Comment: Thanks now it is clear. Am thinking like mysql way to get all 20 records in one query. I will work on that way as u said.

Answer (score 3):

To fetch all the records you can also use scroll concept.. It's like cursor in db's..
If you use scroll, you can get the docs batch by batch.. It will reduce high cpu usage and also memory usage..

For more info refer

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

Comment: I dunno who down voted the answer.. If you down vote say the reason and down vote...

Answer (score 3):

To get all records, per de doc, you should use scroll.
Here is the doc:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

But the idea is to specify your search and indicate that you want to scroll it:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search?scroll=1m' -d '
{
   "query": {
    "match" : {
        "title" : "elasticsearch"
     }
 }
}'
```

in the scroll param you specify how long you want the search results available.

Then you can retrieve them with the returned scroll_id and the scroll api.

Answer (score 0):

in new versions of elastic (e.g. 7.X), it is better to use pagination than scroll (deprecated):
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html

deprecated in 7.0.0:

```
GET /_search/scroll/<scroll_id>
```