# How to configure IBM MobileFirst Platform 8.0 analytics console REST API maximum search result?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, analytics

Why is the Elasticsearch REST API for search and view data via port 9500* returning only 10 records? Is there a maximum number that controls this?

http://localhost:9500/*/_search?q=module:"login"

*https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/analyt
ics/elasticsearch/

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since analytics is based on the elasticsearch, to the query you need to add the additional parameter `&size=100000` to the url.

Example:
http://localhost:9500/_search?size=100000

Comment: Hey thx @krckumar, it works. To make it more robust, is there a way not to hardcode 100000? Any documentation on this?

Comment: In other words is there a infinity value for size? e.g. size=-1 for all records

Comment: @user1872384, this will be helpful to you. not the direct answer but surely an insight :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405341/elastic-search-size-to-unlimited

Comment: Thx Krckumar... the above method works if we are using a webpage/app to access the records online (and we are able to query page by page). However, currently i'm using it to generate a report (in pdf). Hence, i still need all the records. Anyways to count the max records?

Comment: AFAIK, we usually give a very large number so it will cover the subset..

Comment: i see...seems like there's a count function as well... localhost:9500/*/_count?q=module:%22login%22... although i'm able to get the maximum count, if the maximum count is very high it will be causing performance issue...